# How to indicate duplicity exist in column

Tags: excel

How can i indicate duplicity in excel column ? For example i have this rows.

```
c1Indicator1 c2Indicator2
c1row1       c2rowA
c1row2       c2rowB
c1row3       c2rowC
c1row2       c2rowD
c1row4       c2rowE
c1row1       c2rowF
```

In first column is duplicity and in second column is not. Can i for example set Indicator1 text to "!" or background color to red if in column is duplicity ? I dont need exactly find or highlight specific cells which are duplicit, only know if there are any duplicits :-)

thank you

Here is an image for better description:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160903/compare-a-column-itself-to-check-whether-it-have-duplicated-value-in-excel?rq=1

Comment: its not duplicate because i dont want to find duplicates, i want higlight the indicator cell if in specific column exist duplicity.

Comment: could you please clarify what you mean/want? As this question is very misleading/ hard to tell what you are asking at present.

Comment: I add an image, i hope it will be cleare now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional formatting to highlight the duplicates:

Select all of the values in Indicator1 row, on the ribbon home tab press Conditional Formatting> Highlight Cell Rules> Duplicate Values. From there you can choose how you want your duplicates to be formatted.

EDIT: in response to your update

Highlight your header in cell **A1** and click conditional formatting>new rule>Use a formula to determine which cells to format

Assuming your values are in **A2:A7** insert the following formula:

`=(SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(A2:A7)>0,MATCH(A2:A7,A2:A7,0),""),IF(LEN(A2:A7)>0,MATCH(A2:A7,A2:A7,0),""))>0,1)))<>COUNTA(A2:A7)`

Source:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/count-occurrences-of-values-or-unique-values-in-a-data-range-HP003056118.aspx

You will then need to clikc "Format" and select the formatting you would like when that formula evaluates to true - when there are duplicates (e.g. red background)

Comment: Thanks for a tip but i dont want to highlight duplicates, i want only highlight one cell if in specific column exist duplicates.

Comment: See edits to my original post, does that work for you?